# ng-model which uses ng-change not updated by ng-click

Tags: angularjs

**UPDATED**

I think

```
ng-init="currentQuantity=item.quantity"
```

simply prevents **the ng-model currentQuantity** from updating to the next incremented value. Are there any workarounds for this in the example below?

Can i for example target a **currentQuantity model** by **index** so i know which model i'm changing and not all of them at once?

---

I'm currently having issues with AngularJS. By the code beneath i'm adding products to a cart array:

```
QuantityChanged(product, currentQuantity);
```

Next i have a + button next to this input field which just adds +1 of the quantity of the product to the cart.

```
<button class="plus-button" ng-click="addToCart(product);">+</button>
```

My ng-model="currentQuantity" however only updates when using QuantityChanged(product,currentQuantity) but not when i'm using the ng-click="addToCart(product)" function.

If i look in my localstorage i see that the quantity of the cart is succesfully updated but when i look at the current input text field value of the ng-model: currentQuantity i see nothing is changed. When i refresh i'll see the correct value in the input field. Am i missing something obvious?

**View:**

```
<span ng-repeat="item in cart">
      <span ng-if="item.id === product.id">
            <input type="text" ng-change="QuantityChanged(product, currentQuantity);" ng-model="currentQuantity" ng-init="currentQuantity=item.quantity" class="product-aantal"  />
      </span>
</span>

<button class="plus-button" ng-click="addToCart(product);">+</button>
```

**Some Controller Code (if necessary):**

```
$scope.QuantityChanged = function (product, quantity) {

        quantity = parseFloat(quantity, 6);

        $scope.cart.forEach(function (item) {
            if (item.id === product.id) {

                if(item.quantity < quantity){
                    $scope.productCounter = $scope.productCounter + (quantity - item.quantity);
                }
                if(item.quantity > quantity){
                    $scope.productCounter = $scope.productCounter - (item.quantity - quantity);
                }

                item.quantity = quantity;
                item.totalprice = parseFloat(item.price,6) * quantity;
            }
        });

        this.saveProducts($scope.cart);
        this.saveProductCounter($scope.productCounter);

    };


$scope.addToCart = function (product) {

        var found = false;
        $scope.cart.forEach(function (item) {
            if (item.id === product.id) {
                item.quantity++;
                $scope.productCounter++;
                item.totalprice += parseFloat(item.price,6);
                found = true;
            }

        });
        if (!found) {
            $scope.cart.push(angular.extend({quantity: 1, totalprice: parseFloat(product.price,6) }, product));
            $scope.productCounter += 1;
        }


        this.saveProducts($scope.cart);
        this.saveProductCounter($scope.productCounter);

    };
```

Comment: Try forcing a digest with $timeout inside addToCart.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to use this method?

Comment: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/3051/)

Comment: Thanks i tried your example, the $timeout function works but however it's not solving the problem. I'm setting up a mini project now for an alternative solution and post it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is related to the scope of the ng-repeat.

Change the currentQuantity to current.quantity and inside addToCart manipulate that value as well.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n7ad5z14/)

```
if (item.id === product.id) {
    item.quantity++;
    $scope.current.quantity++;
    $scope.productCounter++;
    item.totalprice += parseFloat(item.price,6);
    found = true;
}
```

I must say that your logic is quite hard to understand, but that fixes the problem.

Comment: Thanks this solution works, however you're right. I'm working on an alternative solution that shouldn't have caused this problems in the first place. I will post it later.

Comment: Solved it now with just a simple $index on the ng-repeat and ng-model to target the correct ng-model. Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zgr73s9z/11/